# How to update spf record for Two different domain which are hosted in same ip address

Tags: networking, dns, ip, cpanel, spf

I have two different domains for e.g  : example1.com and example2.com

Both these domains are pointed to same server with two different sites .i.e to two different hosted directories with same ip address.

But the problem is what should be the ip address for both domains to update SPF records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have example.org and example.com

You could have

```
example.com. IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:192.0.2.0/24 ip4:198.51.100.123 a -all"
```

and

```
example.org. IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:192.0.2.0/24 ip4:198.51.100.123 a -all"
```

With no negative consequence whatsoever.

When an spf record is looked up it is checked against the domain, the entity checking the record has no knowledge of any other domain, or any other configuration that is applied. The only thing it is checking for is whether that domain has a record for that IP address.

It is perfectly feasible to have tens of thousands of domains all serving email from the same address and all having a nearly identical SPF record.